# Login without passphrase after FDE

Tags: boot, 20.04, encryption

I installed Ubuntu (image from dell) 20.04 with full disk encryption(FDE).
Encryption went fine but I am forced to enter passphrase which I used for encryption, every time system starts.
Is there a way to bypass the passphrase entry by using TPM or some other mechanism without removing FDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TPM in Ubuntu is handled by the `tcsd`, provided by the `trousers` package. See `man tcsd`.

Comment: Be aware that what you want negates any benefit of encryption if someone has physical access to the machine.